# Logitech H600 wirelss headphones Ubuntu 20

Tags: wireless, logitech, headset

Please, did anyone managed to install Logitech H600 wirelss headset on Ubuntu 20?
I already tested on windows and works as expected.

In Ubuntu20 looks like usb dongle is seen:

```
enkiai@enkiai-desktop:~/Desktop$ lsusb 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c542 Logitech, Inc. Wireless Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But aplay doesn't show device:
(I have 2 video cards)

```
enkiai@enkiai-desktop:~/Desktop$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
enkiai@enkiai-desktop:~/Desktop$
```

I searched for any fixes, but didn't manage to make it work

thank you

Answer (score -1):

In Linux Mint (Ubuntu based) you can use this device without dongle if your motherboard supports Bluetooth.
To connect: press dongle-connect button and volume-up same time for about 10-20 seconds.
Light will flashing very fast and then connection process will start.
Don't forget to use 'high fidelity' sound in sound properties (standard sound is awful).

Microphone didn't work though, but maybe is possible...

Comment: Logitech H600 is not Bluetooth.

Comment: while official specs don't mention bluetooth the headset actually DOES support it. and mic works as well if you switch it to HFP.